# How to Create a Generic Method and Create Instance of The Type

Tags: c#, generics, html-helper

I want to create a helper method that I can imagine has a signature similar to this:

```
public static MyHtmlTag GenerateTag<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj)
{
    // how do I create an instance of MyAnchor? 
    // this returns MyAnchor, which has a MyHtmlTag base
}
```

When I invoke the method, I want to specify a type of MyHtmlTag, such as MyAnchor, e.g.:

```
<%= Html.GenerateTag<MyAnchor>(obj) %>
```

or

```
<%= Html.GenerateTag<MySpan>(obj) %>
```

Can someone show me how to create this method?

Also, what's involved in creating an instance of the type I specified? `Activator.CreateInstance()`?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx):

```
public static MyHtmlTag GenerateTag<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj)
{
    T value = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    // Set properties on value/ use it/etc
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Does using Activator.CreateInstance remove the need for a new() generic type constraint? Is this a good thing?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx
The call to CreateInstance<T>() will fail with an *exception* if there is no parameterless constructor. The example I posted will fail at *compile time* with a useful error about the type passed in to the generic method not having a parameterless constructor. You take your pick for which is "better".

Answer (score 1):

There's existing functionality in [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com) you may want to check out called "[FluentHtml](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/)".  It looks like this:

```
<%=this.TextBox(x => x.FirstName).Class("required").Label("First Name:")%>
<%=this.Select(x => x.ClientId).Options((SelectList)ViewData["clients"]).Label("Client:")%>
<%=this.MultiSelect(x => x.UserId).Options(ViewModel.Users)%>
<%=this.CheckBox("enabled").LabelAfter("Enabled").Title("Click to enable.").Styles(vertical_align => "middle")%>
```

Comment: hmm.. I didn't know that was there. I kind of like doing it myself though. I might take a look at that though if my stuff proves inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the generic constraint of [new()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(VS.80).aspx) to T, then do the following:

```
public static MyHtmlTag GenerateTag<T> (this HtmlHelper helper, T obj) where T : MyHtmlTag, new()
{
    T val = new T ();
    return val;
}
```